# How does the Count function work in a LINQ left join

Tags: c#, linq

So I have this example of a LINQ Query:

```
var productsPerSupplier = from s in suppliers
                          join p in products
                          on s.Id equals p.SupplierId
                          into sp
                          select new
                          {
                              SupplierId = s.Id,
                              SupplierName = s.Name,
                              ProductCount = sp.Count()
                          };
```

How does the count function know to count the number of products for each supplier? What is the structure of sp table? Isn't it supposed to count all the rows in the table?

This is the result:
[image]

Answer (score 2):

See [here in the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/join-clause?redirectedfrom=MSDN#group-join). `into` keyword creates hierarchical grouping in the results where each item in the left table is associated with one or more items in the right table of your `join`. This is why it knows how to perform `Count()` on individual groups.

Comment: thank you for your answer, and the `GROUP BY` keyword isn't mandatory, the query works like this too.

Answer (score 1):

Try following :

```
var productsPerSupplier = (from s in suppliers
                          join p in products
                          on s.Id equals p.SupplierId
                          select new {s = s, p = p}
                          ).GroupBy(x => x.s.ID)
                          .Select(x => new
                          {
                              SupplierId = x.Key,
                              SupplierName = x.s.First().Name,
                              ProductCount = x.Count()
                          }).ToList();
```

Comment: Cannot access field `s` at `x.s.First().Name`
Edit: I switched `First()` with `s` and now it's working, you meant to do an inner join here?

Comment: Try x.First().s.Name